# Does the Klingon spoken in Star Trek: Discovery present a harsh/ventricular/pressed voice phonation?

Tags: phonetics, prosody, constructed-language, conlang

The new Klingon dialogue sounds noticeably different, perhaps they could be using a sound filter or simply acting in a lower register; although Klingon character Voq's voice sounds particularly restricted.

I found no mention to this detail except for 'harsh voice' being used alongside 'guttural,' 'clipped,' 'fierce,' 'unusual' and other informal descriptions of the Klingon language.

Answer (score 2):

This is properly the domain of https://conlang.stackexchange.com , but at least one actor  in Discovery (the one who played T'Kuvma) made a point of saying that he wanted his Klingon to sound African (http://hellenisteukontos.opoudjis.net/what-is-tkuvma-saying-in-the-trailer/, citing https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/72v35m/i_transcribed_all_of_tkuvmas_speeches_to_get_a/ ). Different prosthetics are likely in play as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nick. I'm still figuring out the guidelines. That's some interesting links. I'd never thought about the obvious relationship between dentistry and linguistic field research. That's certainly nightmarish!

Comment: The punctiliousness of Stack Exchange about scope is one of its less endearing characteristics compared to comparable fora (I'm a refugee from Quora).

Comment: >the obvious relationship between dentistry and linguistic field research.

The melancholy stories of the last speaker of a language having no teeth are ones fieldworkers trot out regularly.